# casperjs: get form field value

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have an v1.0.0-RC4 casper version without `Casper.getFormValues()` useful function and I can't to upgrade casper by some reasons.

Is there any other way to get form fields values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the answer was found: to get a field value, have a look at `ClientUtils.getFieldValue()`

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(this.evaluate(function() {
        return __utils__.getFieldValue('fieldName');
    }));
});
```